# Race condition between signal handling and fork()

Tags: c, process, posix

I want to install a signal handler to propagate `SIGHUP` to children in another process group, but it seems that in POSIX I can only get the PID of the children from the return of `fork()`.

So, is there a way to avoid the race condition that happens when you receive the SIGHUP before `fork()` has returned in the parent, but after `setpgid()` has already been executed in the child?

Comment: What do you intend to do in the signal handler? The signal handler could set a flag that causes the main code to not `fork` anymore and to send the signal to all children at a suitable place after returning from a possibly pending `fork`.

Comment: I intent to relay the signal to child and `abort()`.

Comment: This should be part of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I reworded to make it more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> it seems that in POSIX I can only get the PID of the children from the return of `fork()`.

Certainly you can't get child PIDs *before* `fork()` returns, as the child doesn't exist until then in the parent's timeline.  And the return value of `fork()` is indeed the POSIX-blessed way for the parent to get that PID, yes.

> So, is there a way to avoid the race condition that happens when you receive the SIGHUP before `fork()` has returned in the parent, but after `setpgid()` has already been executed in the child?

Yes.  Have the parent block `SIGHUP` before forking (see [`sigprocmask()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html)).  Parent and / or child (which inherits the parent's signal dispositions) should then unblock `SIGHUP` when they are ready.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly forwarding a signal inside the signal handler, it could set a flag that prevents the main code from `fork`ing and causes it to send the signal to the children at a suitable place after processing the return value of a pending `fork`.

Edit: This avoids the problematic cases and postpones the forwarding of the signal to a safe situation.

Pseudo code example (not valid C):

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sighup_occurred = 0;

void sighup_handler(int sig) {
    sighup_occurred = 1;
}

int main(void) {

    sigaction(SIGHUP, ...);

    while(some_condition){
        if(!sighup_occurred) {
            pid = fork();
            /* distinction between parent and child needed here */
            pids[child_count++] = pid;
        }

        if(sighup_occurred) {
            for(int i = 0; i < child_count; i++) {
                kill(pids[i], SIGHUP);
            }
            terminate_program();
        } else {
            do_normal_work();
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the program, the flag `sighup_occurred` could also be used to exit the main loop, and the `kill`ing of the children could be done after the loop.

---

Additional explanation as a response to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120975/race-condition-between-signal-handling-and-fork/76122029?noredirect=1#comment134259523_76122029).

As I understand the question and the additional information in the OP's comment, the race condition is not the **reception** of the signal vs. return from `fork` but the actions performed in the signal handler or, more generally, performed as a reaction to the reception of the signal in the parent.

The parent is supposed to forward the signal to the children. According to my understanding, there are a few different cases:

1. no child yet - nothing to do
2. child in parent's process group - sending signal to parent's process group will signal the child
3. child has called `setpgid` and is in a new process group, but the PID returned from `fork` is not yet stored - child can no longer be
   signalled using the parent's process group, child PID not yet known
4. child's PID returned from `fork` is stored - child can be signalled using its PID

This proposed solution delays the execution of the expected actions caused by the signal handler until the PID returned from `fork` is stored. This reduces the possible cases to 1 and 4 which do not have the problem of case
3.

My interpretation might be wrong, but to me it seemed to be clear when I wrote the answer.